# AsyncCqlTemplate Cached Prepared Statement with Insert

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring-data-cassandra 2.0.7.RELEASE and I am having a hard time figuring out how to get a `cached` prepared statement.

In similar fashion I used the CqlTemplate template and created a `PreparedStatementCache` and am able to create a cached prepared statement like so:

```
    PreparedStatementCreator preparedStatementCreator = ...;
    PreparedStatementBinder  binder                   = ...;

    return selectCqlTemplate.query(preparedStatementCreator,
                                   binder,
                                   resultSetExtractor);
```

For the AsyncCqlTemplate I see there is a `AsyncPreparedStatementCreator` but it's not very clear how to create one of these as the only implementation is `SimpleAsyncPreparedStatementCreator` which is private.

So my question is, for an insert statement what's the best way to use AsyncCqlTemplate and have a cached prepared statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data for Apache Cassandra does not provide a built-in asynchronous `PreparedStatement` cache. It ships only with a synchronous one ([`CachedPreparedStatementCreator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/support/CachedPreparedStatementCreator.html), [`PreparedStatementCache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/support/PreparedStatementCache.html)).

Implementing an asynchronous cache requires some effort in terms of synchronization and to avoid duplicate prepare calls.

A simple implementation could look like:

```
public class AsyncCachedPreparedStatementCreator implements AsyncPreparedStatementCreator, CqlProvider {

    private final String cql;

    private final Map<Session, com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture<PreparedStatement>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public AsyncCachedPreparedStatementCreator(String cql) {
        this.cql = cql;
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<PreparedStatement> createPreparedStatement(Session session) throws DriverException {

        com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture<PreparedStatement> future = cache.computeIfAbsent(session,
                s -> s.prepareAsync(cql));

        return new GuavaListenableFutureAdapter<>(future, new CassandraExceptionTranslator());
    }

    @Override
    public String getCql() {
        return cql;
    }
}
```

This implementation assumes a per-`Session` cache and holds its cache in a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was just surprised there isn't a simple implementation for a cached async prepared statement. I will go ahead and create a feature for this in spring boot cassandra as I think having a simple implementation included in the module is probably a good idea.